# Scroll child element when in viewport

Tags: javascript, scroll, parent-child, event-listener, intersection-observer

Can someone help?

I have multiple sticky child elements, some of these has an high height (more than the viewport).
Each child has the following structure:

```
<section>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="child"></div>
    ... 20 more child ...
  </div>
</section>
```

with the following css:

```
section {
  min-height: 682px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 80px;
}
.content {
  height: 618px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 5px;
}
.child {
  height: 120px;
}
```

How can i achieve this scroll behaviour:

1. first i scroll normally the body
2. when i reach the section with high height i need to scroll the section until i touch the bottom
3. when i reach the bottom of the section i need to scroll normally the body

I need to achieve this without manually scroll the section content but only scrolling the body scrollbar..

I already write the IntersectionObserver that observe the section with high height.

I think a simple solution is to change the "focus" of the scroll between parent and child when necessary but I don't know what the best way to solve this is in js.

I already try to add a scroll event listener and then scroll the content of the section with section.scrollBy(0, event.deltaY);

But the event.deltaY doesnt exist in the type event: Event in ts...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a combination of Intersection Observer and event listeners.

You can set Intersection Observer to observe the section with high height and
when it becomes fully visible in the viewport,trigger a function.

```
const section = document.querySelector('section');

const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      // Call a function to handle scrolling behavior
      handleSectionScroll();
    }
  });
});

observer.observe(section);
```

In the handleSectionScroll function, you can add a scroll event listener to the body to control the scrolling behavior.

```
const handleSectionScroll = () => {
  document.body.addEventListener('wheel', scrollBody);

  const scrollBody = (event) => {
    const sectionHeight = section.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    const bodyHeight = document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    const scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;

    if (scrollPosition < section.offsetTop) {
      // Scroll normally
      return;
    }

    if (scrollPosition >= section.offsetTop && scrollPosition < 
       section.offsetTop + sectionHeight - bodyHeight) {
       // Scroll the section
       section.scrollBy(0, event.deltaY);
       event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      // Scroll normally
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Try this code and let me know the result.